# Reading into list and picking specific numbers

Tags: c#, list, streamreader

A request came in for an app written a long time ago, they wanted another column on an existing datagridview with current drilling times.  These times come from a file that machines read and run.  Below is an example of a file.

[image: Machine Program]

Now the numbers there looking for are the ones with an S.  Now, the very first number is the line number.  The line number needs grabbed too as the time's need to match up with the line.  So I have to read this into a list, grab the line number and then the associated "s" time number.  I will be adding these "s times" to an existing table which already has the line numbers so I'll add these "s times" to a new column next to the corresponding line number.  I'm a bit stuck here.

Any help is appreciated.

I know I can read everything in like this

```
         string f = ("//dnc/WJ/MTI-WJ/" + cboPartProgram.Text);

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
        {
            // Use while != null pattern for loop
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }
```

But once in a list I need to ignore lines that start with an apostrophe " ' ", then take only the first line number "1, 2, 3" etc for however many there are and then the "s" number of that line.

So that I'm left with:

```
1    2.75
2    2.5
3    2
```

...etc

Now, on the database there is a program table.  with columns

```
Program  Line  Time
Program1  1    
Program1  2
Program1  3
Program1  4
```

etc

So the "s" times will be added to the time column of the existing table.  But the "s" times taken from line 1,2,3,4 and so on will coincide with the line column of the table.

So, the final end result in this example would be

```
Program  Line  Time
Program1  1    2.75
Program1  2    2.5
Program1  3    2
```

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure if the edited code to cover the lines w/out the sTime work yet because I'm ran into an issue recently.  There is a datagridview that populates the columns from a list filled from a sql statement.  I've added a column for the sTime (turns out I may not need the line# so you'll notice I removed that) however I need to incorporate my loop from sTime into the loop that is occurring for the list that is also populating the dgv.  Now I've tried to incorporate this in a couple of different ways however what happens is either the very last sTime is use for all 80 entries of the dgv (as the example below does) or if I move the " } " brackets around some and combine them then uses the first sTime to create 80 entries of dgv, then the 2nd sTime to create 80 entries of the dgv.  So instead of 80 entries in dgv with each individual sTime next to it, you end up with 6,400 entries in dgv 80x80.  so I'm not sure how to combine these 2 to work.

```
        var sLines = File.ReadAllLines("//dnc/WJ/MTI-WJ/" + cboPartProgram.Text)
             .Where(s => !s.StartsWith("'"))
             .Select(s => new
             {
                 SValue = Regex.Match(s, "(?<=S)[\\d.]*").Value
             })
             .ToArray();

        string lastSValue = "";
        foreach (var line in sLines)
        {
            string val = line.SValue == string.Empty ? lastSValue : line.SValue;
            lastSValue = val;
        }



            foreach (WjDwellOffsets offset in dwellTimes)
            {
                origionalDwellOffsets.Add(offset.dwellOffset);

                dgvDwellTimes.Rows.Add(new object[] { offset.positionId, lastSValue, offset.dwellOffset, 0, offset.dwellOffset, "Update", (offset.dateTime > new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)) ? offset.dateTime.ToString() : "" });
                DataGridViewDisableButtonCell btnCell = ((DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)dgvDwellTimes.Rows[dgvDwellTimes.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[5]);
                btnCell.Enabled = false;
            }
```

Comment: What's the question? Where's your code? Have you tried *anything?*

Comment: if you tried anything please post code ...

Comment: Well the question is how to begin really.  This is unlike me to have nothing else but it just goes to show how stuck I feel I guess.  I'm not sure if I should read everything into a list?  Or if I should read only the line number in, then read the "s" number in? I don't usually work with files/code like this so I don't know where to begin. The person who worked on this stuff quit and it was dropped on my desk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only condition is to keep the lines that have an "S" in them, and if that data sample is indicative of the overall line pattern, then this is quite simple (and you can use Regex to further filter your results):

```
var sLines = File.ReadAllLines("filepath.txt")
                 .Where(s => !s.StartsWith("'") && s.Contains("S"))
                 .Select(s => new 
                 { 
                     LineNumber = Regex.Match(s, "^\\d*").Value,
                     SValue = Regex.Match(s, "(?<=S)[\\d.]*").Value
                 })
                 .ToArray();

// Use like this
foreach (var line in sLines)
{
    string num = line.LineNumber;
    string val = line.SValue;
}
```

---

To maintain *all* lines and just have relevant information on some, this method can be a bit tweaked, but it will also require a bit of some outside processing.

```
var sLines = File.ReadAllLines("filepath.txt")
                 .Where(s => !s.StartsWith("'"))
                 .Select(s => new 
                 { 
                     LineNumber = Regex.Match(s, "^\\d*").Value,
                     SValue = Regex.Match(s, "(?<=S)[\\d.]*").Value
                 })
                 .ToArray();

// Use like this
string lastSValue = "";
foreach (var line in sLines)
{
    string num = line.LineNumber;
    string val = line.SValue == string.Empty ? lastSValue : line.SValue;

    // Do the stuff

    lastSValue = val;
}
```

Comment: I added some more info to show what my end result needs to be.

Comment: I'm going to try this in just a moment, however just a quick glance, does this ignore lines with an apostrophe? The lines w/ an apostrophe are commented out lines, I don't want those.  Also, will I need to use forward slash "//d" as an example or perhaps I'm missing a class.

Comment: @Lee Yes, that is what the `!s.StartsWith("'")` is there for, and no, you shouldn't use double forward slash as the regular expression uses double backslash for a reason.

Comment: that worked, that's awesome.  I have, what I at least consider to be a pain but maybe its just as easy.  There are some lines that don't have an "s" number.  The lines that don't have an "s" number are supposed to use the last "s" number used until the next line with an "s" number begins.  Is that an easy adjustment?

Comment: @Lee Not especially. I don't think that the solution would be terribly difficult, but that extra information completely changes the scenario, and this current solution as it is wouldn't work at all.

Comment: I see.  I'm sorry I hadn't mentioned that, had I known it would have resulting in something else entirely I would have made it clear.

Comment: Is that something you can assist me with?  If not, your busy or its just too much I understand.

Comment: @Lee After getting some sleep, I realized that you *can* tweak this solution to get your desired result. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help here, can you check out my updated edit?